# Subspace of $ \mathbb{R}^2 $

Tags: vector-spaces, matrix-equations

I  wanted to know whether $$   V=\{ (a, b) :a, b, \in \mathbb{R}\} $$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Now,  it is clear $V  $ contains the origin of $\mathbb{R}  ^2$ and is also closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication.  **But still my book says that it is not a subspace.** Is there anything which I am missing?

Comment: You must be missing something because this is certainly $\mathbb{R}^2$, which is trivially a subspace of itself.

Comment: Perhaps your book meant a proper subspace?

Comment: A point $(a,b)$ is a vector subspace iff $a=b=0.$. Its dimension is $0$.

Comment: @copper.hat No it just said subspace.

Comment: And where is the matrix equation?

Comment: Your edit has confused things a bit... A subspace is a set of points.

Comment: Looking at the actual code I think he just isn't familiar with LaTeX.

Comment: Not sure if your book is nit picking, We can identify every vector from $\mathbb{R}^2$ with a pair of reals, in that sense they are the same set. Of course a vector space is a set of vectors together with scalar multiplication and vector addition, obeying the vector space axioms, so it is more than just a set of real valued pairs.

Comment: @mvw: If it were asking if this set was a *vector space*, that could be somewhat plausible, but according to him it's acting if this is a *subspace* of $\mathbb{R}^2$.  It stretches credibility to assume the desired answer was "maybe not, because I can't tell if this is even a *subset* of $\mathbb{R}^2$ from your definition."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated, your space is certainly a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$, since it is all of $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Assuming that this is the problem in the book, their answer is wrong.